# jquery change variable permanently on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This does not seem to be working the way I would expect:

```
$("#thing").click(function(aVar) { 
   //run aFunc();
   aVar = "test";
   alert(aVar)
   return aVar;
});

if(typeof aVar === "undefined") { 
   $("#gniht").html("still undefined");
}
```

Every time I click, the function runs and the alert says "test", but aVar is still undefined (i.e. #gniht doesn't get populated with aVar's "test").

I want to be able to click the button and store the value "test" to the aVar and then use aVar outside the scope of the button function. How do I do that?

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/5xsthbxy/10/

Comment: Well, the last three lines are only executed *once* when the page loads. Code that is supposed to be executed on click has to be inside or called from the event handler.

Comment: Zoltar, it is your question is unclear. Create a jsfiddle to clear up things, please.

Comment: `aVar` is a parameter to the function and thus has a restricted scope that may be the issue here. You do realize that using the same name in multiple places can cause issues, right?

Comment: I added a jsfiddle example. I want to be able to click the button and store the value "test" to the aVar and then use aVar outside the scope of the button function. How do I do that?

Comment: Define the variable outside the scope of the button function perhaps?

Comment: That if statement is not going to magically run. It runs once and that is it.

Comment: The answer to this was `var aVar = $("#thing").click(function(aVar) { 
  aVar = "test";
   return aVar;
});`

Answer (score 1):

`aVar` is undefined quite simply because you never define it (in your posted code). Add this at the beginning:

```
var avar = 'Some value';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/chcuemo0/

To explain a bit more about your code snippet, let me add some comments for you:

```
var aVar = 'some value';   // Declare the variable

$("#thing").click(function (aVar) {
    //aFunc();       // I removed this from my jsFiddle because it's not defined here so it breaks the program.
    aVar = "test"; // modify the variable
    alert(aVar); // announce the variable
    return aVar; // This sends the variable back to the click handler, doing nothing useful in this snippet.
});

// Here you check to see if the variable is undefined
// If it is undefined, you try to use it - this breaks the program
if (typeof aVar === "undefined") {
    $("#gniht").html(aVar);
}
```

---

To modify the variable in the click event and use it elsewhere, you simply need to have it defined outside the scope of the click function prior to setting it inside. For example:

```
var aVar = 'some value';

$("#thing").click(function () {
    aVar = "test";
});

$("#thing2").click(function () {
    $("#print").html(aVar);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/chcuemo0/1/

---

If it must for some reason not be defined prior to the click event, you can use `window.` to attach it to the global scope.

```
$("#thing").click(function () {
    window.aVar = "test";
});

$("#thing2").click(function () {
    $("#print").html(aVar);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/chcuemo0/2/

Comment: I want to define the aVar variable by clicking, I don't want it defined prior.

Comment: Why not? Anyways, see my update. You can use `window.aVar` which will attach it globally as well

Answer (score 1):

**Issue with the existing implementation :**

The following function is executed only once. i.e, during page load, which checks if aVar is undefined.

```
if(typeof aVar === "undefined") { 
   $("#gniht").html(aVar);
}
```

When the button is clicked, the value of aVar is set to 'test'. However, this new updated value is not being used anywhere in the implementation.

```
$("#thing").click(function(aVar) { 
   aVar = "test";
   alert(aVar);
});
```

**Possible Approach to Fix :**

The following code would update `aVar` declared locally inside the click function of the button and set the html of `gniht` outside the scope of that.

```
$("#thing").click(function() { 
   aVar = "test";
   alert(aVar);
   GetValue();
});

function GetValue()
{
    if(typeof aVar === "undefined") 
       $("#gniht").html("still undefined");
    else
        $("#gniht").html(aVar);
}

GetValue();
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/5xsthbxy/11/

Comment: the answer provided is based on the same question being asked " store the value "test" to the aVar and then use aVar outside the scope of the button function"